# Floating Point Exception C

Tags: c, exception, floating-point

I keep getting this error while testing the following function. It's supposed to normalize the values of an image that contains pixels of colors 0 to 255. I found the min and max, changed them to 0 and 255, then changed all inbetween values accordingly to accomodate the same previous ratio of difference:

```
void normalize( uint8_t array[],
        unsigned int cols,
        unsigned int rows )
{
  uint8_t minValue = 255;
  uint8_t maxValue = 0; 

  for (int i = 0; i < cols*rows ; ++i)
    {
      if(array[i] < minValue) minValue = array[i];
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < cols*rows; ++i)
    {
      if(array[i] < maxValue) maxValue = array[i];
    }

  int difference1 = maxValue - minValue;

  uint8_t ratios[cols*rows];

  for (int i = 0; i < cols*rows ; ++i){
    ratios[i] = 0;
  }

  //find the ratios
  for (int i = 0; i < cols*rows ; ++i){
    ratios[i] = (array[i] / difference1) - 1;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < cols*rows ; ++i){

    if(array[i] == minValue){
      array[i] = 0;
    }else if(array[i] == maxValue){
      array[i] = 255;
    }else{
      array[i] = round(ratios[i] * 255);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're getting a divide-by-zero error when `difference1` is zero

Comment: And the `difference1` is 0 because `minValue` is equal to `maxValue`, as soon as there is a black pixel on the image.

Comment: Thanks! I totally did not see the error in the if statement.

Comment: Also note that you can determine min and max in a single loop, rather than needing two loops over the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mis-calculation of `max.

Even though code should be as below, that is not all.

```
// if(array[i] < maxValue) maxValue = array[i];
if(array[i] > maxValue) maxValue = array[i];
```

Code should still work if all the pixels were that same color (`difference1 == 0`).  A simple solution is to leave `array[]` alone in that case.

```
int difference1 = maxValue - minValue;
if (difference1 > 0) {
  uint8_t ratios[cols*rows];
  ...
      array[i] = round(ratios[i] * 255);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this correct?

void normalize( uint8_t array[],
        unsigned int cols,
        unsigned int rows )
{

```
//each pixel is rounded by 255 * (index-lowest_pixel_val_in_array) divided by ( highest value pixel minus lowest value pixel)

 // your code here
uint8_t minValue = 255; //255 means WHITE
uint8_t maxValue = 0;  // 0 MEANS BLACK 

for (int i = 0; i < cols*rows ; ++i) //PREINCREMENT means if i= 1 and j=++i=2/
{
  if(array[i] < minValue) 
minValue = array[i]; //make minimum value the array

  if(array[i]  > maxValue) 
 maxValue = array[i]; //make maximum value for array
}

int difference = maxValue - minValue; //the difference is maximum - minimum
```

// uint8_t ratios[cols*rows]; //CHANGED PUT THIS INSIDE

```
if(difference > 0) //ENSURE MAX != MIN
{ 
uint8_t ratios[cols*rows]; //CHANGED PUT THIS INSIDE 
for (int i = 0; i < cols*rows ; ++i) //PREINCREMENT means if i= 1 and j=++i. j becomes 2 but for i++ j wuld be 1
{
      ratios[i] = 0; //SET IT 0 INTIALLY. 
      ratios[i] = (array[i] / difference) - 1; //subtract 1st pixel and CALCULATE RATIOS


      if(array[i] == minValue)
          {
          array[i] = 0; //lightest becomes darkest
          }

      else if(array[i] == maxValue)
      {
          array[i] = 255; //darkest becomes lightest
          }

      else
      {
          array[i] = round(ratios[i] * 255); //ROUND THE PIXEL
          }
}
}
```

}